# ニュースのタイトル表示は、52バイト内に表示させたい

Tags: javascript, php

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
if(strlen($item->T03_PROMOTION_TITLE)>31) echo mb_substr( $item->T03_PROMOTION_TITLE, 0, 26,"UTF8"); else echo $item->T03_PROMOTION_TITLE;?></a></div>
                                    <div class="bs_font16 ellipsis"><a class="" href="<?php echo appSettings::strWebURL.'/newsdetail/index.php?P=0&ID='.$item->T03_PROMOTION_ID.'&CBR='.$item->T03_PROMOTION_CATEGORY.'#main'?>"><?php if(mb_strlen($item->T03_PROMOTION_CONTENT, '8bit')>160) echo mb_substr( $item->T03_PROMOTION_CONTENT, 0, 51,"UTF8").'...'; else echo $item->T03_PROMOTION_CONTENT;?>
```

日本語場合、26文字を表示される。
英語場合、52文字を表示される。
日本語と英語を混じった文書は、どのようなコマンドを使用するでしょうか。
教えていただけませんか。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 状況がよく分かりません。実際のコードを書いていただくなどして、どのような問題なのかもっと具体的に説明して頂けませんか？　質問文の下の「編集」から追記ができます。

Comment: 参考: Unicode を使う場合、日本語の文字に限ったとしても 1 文字 2 バイトとは限りません。英語の文字に限ったとしても、たとえばアクセント記号がついたラテン・アルファベットは 1 文字 1 バイトではありません。ご注意下さい。

Comment: 日本語場合、26文字を表示される。
英語場合、52文字を表示される。
日本語と英語を混じった文書は、どのようなコマンドを使用するでしょうか。
教えていただけませんか。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。状況はいくらか分かりやすくなりました。今回の実装では「それぞれの場合で文字数が揃う」ことと、「文字を表示させたときに縦と横の幅がぴったりになる」こととではどちらが重要ですか？　たとえばギリシャ文字　α, β, γ... は表示する環境によって[文字幅が異なる](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%B1%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A2%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%B9%85)ので、文字数を揃えたとしても幅は揃わないかもしれません。

Comment: 仕様は、タイトル文字は、横幅（210px）と縦幅（2行）の条件でどの文字種でも表示できること。
困っている問題は、
文字種は、日本語（2バイト）
文字種は、英語（1バイト）
文字種は、日本語と英語を混じった場合実装が難しいです。

Comment: ですから、「それぞれの場合で文字数が揃う」ことは一番重要だと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

2行分の文字を表示したいという場合は別のアプローチでの解決方法もあるかと思います。

## cssで2列の範囲外を見えなくする

単純にエリアに２も自分の領域のみ表示するようにしてそれ以降は見えなくしてしまう

```
.area {
  height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

## 範囲外を3てんリーダーにする

ブラウザは限られてきそうですが、CSSで対応できるようです
https://tech.recruit-mp.co.jp/front-end/tips-ellipsis/

文字列で数えるなどの場合いろいろ考えることが多くなるため
cssでの対応のが簡単かなと思ったのでご提案です。

Answer (score 1):

僕も CSS で解決したほうがいいと思うけど。
半角文字（ASCII）を `a` に置換し、全角文字（非ASCII）を `Aa` に置換し、
先頭から52文字中にある `a` の数が先頭から切り出すべき文字数の目安です。

```
<?php
function abbreviate($title, $length)
{
    $tmp = $title;
    $tmp = preg_replace('/[\\x20-\\x7E]/iu', 'a', $tmp);
    $tmp = preg_replace('/[^a]/iu', 'Aa', $tmp);
    $tmp = substr($tmp, 0, 52);
    $length = substr_count($tmp, 'a');
    return mb_substr($title, 0, $length, 'UTF-8');
}

$title = '確認テストtesttesttest確認テストtest確認テストtesttesttest';
echo $title, PHP_EOL;
echo abbreviate($title, 52), PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;

$title = 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest';
echo $title, PHP_EOL;
echo abbreviate($title, 52), PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;

$title = '確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト';
echo $title, PHP_EOL;
echo abbreviate($title, 52), PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
```

結果

```
% php abbreviate.php
確認テストtesttesttest確認テストtest確認テストtesttesttest
確認テストtesttesttest確認テストtest確認テストtestte

testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest

確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト
確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト確認テスト確
```

非ASCII文字、かつ、文字幅が半角相当の文字が含まれる場合は意図した挙動になりません。